# IOS13+ NSPersistentCloudKitContainer UIRefreshControl how to refresh UITableView content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, icloud

I am using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` to sync data. What would be the correct code to refresh the UITableView content with the new iCloud content? If I close the UITableView and reopen it, the new content appears immediate.

I am using the standard code to refresh the UITableView but with that code I don't get the new data from iCloud?

```
class listFirmenTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        firmenTableView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        firmenTableView.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action:
                                           #selector(handleRefreshControl),
                                           for: .valueChanged)
    }


@objc func handleRefreshControl() {
    reload(tableView: self.tableView)

   // Dismiss the refresh control.
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.firmenTableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
   }
}


func reload(tableView: UITableView) {

    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Comment: Using NSFetchedResultsController and NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate is the way to go here. It will automatically update the table when the database changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please give a little more details about the solution you have in mind?

Comment: I've added a full answer here, but as you can see there's quite a lot to it, so let me know if I missed anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `NSFetchedResultsController` will keep your table in sync with the `CoreData` database automatically. In the code below, you'll have to replace instances of `YourEntityName` with the real database entity name that you're using in your project.

You might also want to set `request.sortDescriptors` appropriately. For example, if you are using a search bar you could include the search bar text in the sort descriptors, and then you'd have to call the method `updateFetchedResultsController()` each time the search bar text changes.

As for the `UIRefreshControl`, it shouldn't even be required after this.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    var container: NSPersistentContainer? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer

    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<YourEntityName>? {
        didSet {
            fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateFetchedResultsController()
    }

    func updateFetchedResultsController() {
        guard let context = container?.viewContext else {
            return
        }

        context.performAndWait {
            let request: NSFetchRequest<YourEntityName> = YourEntityName.fetchRequest()
            request.sortDescriptors = nil // set sort descriptors if you want data ordered specifically
            request.predicate = nil // set predicate if you only want specific data

            fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<YourEntityName>(
                fetchRequest: request,
                managedObjectContext: context,
                sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                cacheName: nil
            )

            do {
                try fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
                tableView.reloadData()
            } catch {
                // Handle the error, for example, present an alert
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK:- UITableViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController?.sections, sections.count > 0 {
            return sections[section].numberOfObjects
        }
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController?.sections, sections.count > 0 {
            return sections[section].name
        }
        return nil
    }

    override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return fetchedResultsController?.sectionIndexTitles
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController?.section(forSectionIndexTitle: title, at: index) ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell        
        let object = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath)
        // use data in object to update your cell
        return cell
    }

    // MARK:- NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        switch type {
        case .insert: tableView.insertSections([sectionIndex], with: .fade)
        case .delete: tableView.deleteSections([sectionIndex], with: .fade)
        default: break
        }
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .update:
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .move:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Also, make sure that you set `container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true` in the `AppDelegate` like so:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "YourEntityName")

    container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
        if let error = error {
            // handle the error
        }
    }

    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    return container
}()
```

Comment: Many thanks worked as expected (and I had to add a sortDescriptor). I put the updateFetchedResultsController() in my refreshControl, so the user can trigger an update, too! myTableView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        myTableView.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action:
                                           #selector(handleRefreshControl),
                                           for: .valueChanged)

Comment: Great, happy to help!

Comment: However, I don't think it's really necessary to call updateFetchedResultsController() in the refreshControl, unless it changes the sortDescriptors or predicate. The whole point of NSFetchedResultsController is that it automatically updates the table when the database changes, so no need to do it manually. If you insist on using a refresh control, I think just calling tableView.reloadData() should be enough?